# getItem in FragmentPagerAdapter not working as expected

Tags: android

I have the below code in my app.

From my understanding I expect that after Main activity is loaded `getItem` from Tab Adapter should be called with `index: 1` as it is set as tab-1 `.setTabListener(this), 1,true);`

But instead of it `getItem` gets called twice first with `index: 0` and then `index: 1`. Why is that can anyone explain?

```
//Main activity code:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        …
        // Tabs Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.TabHandler);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[0])
                .setTabListener(this), 0, false);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[1])
                .setTabListener(this), 1,true);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs[2])
                .setTabListener(this), 2, false);
}

//And this inside the `Tab Adapter`
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new ZeroViewFragment();
            case 1:
                return new OneViewFragment();
            case 2:
                return new TwoViewFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: no it is the correct behavior of the ViewPager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is beacause the `ViewPager` loads not only the visible fragment but the left and right fragments too. So in your case the visible fragment is #0, there is not left fragment and the right fragment is #1. The result is that fragments #0 and #1 are loaded. This behavior is implemented for performance reasons because this way the `ViewPager` has the next fragment prepared and ready to be shown and there will be no lag when swiping between pages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31476778/pager-adapter-not-displaying-image-after-getting-from-response-in-fragment